# Splitting a string to an array using a regex to obtain key-values pairs

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing a text but I can't obtain a piece when a space is missing (which is OK)
**Edit:** I have added colons to the free text.
**Edit:** well, this is an arbitrary text format in which key-value pairs can be written. discarding element[0], the rest of the elements on the array result in a sequence of key value. And it accepts multiline values.

This is the test case text:

```
:part1  only one \s removed:OK
:part2 :text :with
new lines
on it
:noSpaceAfterThis
:thisShoudBeAStandAlongText but: here there are more text
:part4 :even more text
```

This is what I want:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => part1
    [2] =>  only one \s removed:OK
    [3] => part2
    [4] => :text :with
new lines
on it
    [5] => noSpaceAfterThis
    [6] => 
    [7] => thisShoudBeAStandAlongText
    [8] => but: here there are more text
    [9] => part4
    [10] => :even more text
)
```

This is what I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => part1
    [2] =>  only one \s removed:OK
    [3] => part2
    [4] => :text :with
new lines
on it
    [5] => noSpaceAfterThis
    [6] => :thisShoudBeAStandAlongText but: here there are more text
    [7] => part4
    [8] => :even more text
)
```

And this is my testing code:

```
<?php
$text = '
:part1  only one \s removed:OK
:part2 :text :with
new lines
on it
:noSpaceAfterThis
:thisShoudBeAStandAlongText but: here there are more text
:part4 :even more text';

echo '<pre>';
// my effort so far:
$ret = preg_split('|\r?\n:([\w\d]+)(?:\r?\s)?|i', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($ret);

// nor this one:
$ret = preg_split('|\r?\n:([\w\d]+)\r?\s?|i', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($ret);

// for debuging, an extra capturing group
$ret = preg_split('|\r?\n:([\w\d]+)(\r?\s)?|i', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
var_dump($ret);
```

Comment: It would help others to know what the rules are, i.e. why should it match the way you want? :)

Comment: @Jack you a right, I expect you agree the edit I have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An other approach with preg_match_all:

```
$pattern = '~(?<=^:|\n:)\S++|(?<=\s)(?:[^:]+?|(?<!\n):)+?(?= *+(?>\n:|$))~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($matches[0], true);
```

Pattern details:

```
# capture all the first word at line begining preceded by a colon #
(?<=^:|\n:)       # lookbehind, preceded by the begining of the string
                  # and a colon or a newline and a colon
\S++              # all that is not a space

# capture all the content until the next line with : at first position #
(?<=\s)           # lookbehind, preceded by a space
(?:               # open a non capturing group
   [^:]+?         # all character that is not a colon, one or more times (lazy)
  |               # OR
   (?<!^|\n):     # negative lookbehind, a colon not preceded by a newline
                  # or the begining of the string
)+?               # close the non capturing group, 
                  #repeat one or more times (lazy)
(?= *+(?>\n:|$))  # lookahead, followed by spaces (zero or more) and a newline 
                  # with colon at first position or the end of the string
```

The advantage here is to avoid the void results.

or with preg_split:

```
$res = preg_split('~(?:\s*\n|^):(\S++)(?: )?~', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Explanations:

The goal is to split the text in two situations:

- on newlines when the first character is `:`
- at the first space of the line when the line begin by `:`

Thus two points of splitting are arounds this `:word` at the begining of a line.
The `:` and the space after must be removed, but the word must be preserved. This is the reason why i use PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE to keep the word.

pattern details:

```
(?:           # non capturing group (all inside will be removed)
   \s*\n      # trim the spaces of the precedent line and the newline
  |           # OR
   ^          # it is the begining of the string
)             # end of the non capturing group
:             # remove the first character when it is a :
(\S++)        # keep the first word with DELIM_CAPTURE
(?: )?        # remove the first space if present
```

Comment: @LuisSiquot: Oups! Sorry for the typo. Thanks

Comment: Sorry. I have edited my question, the spliting colons must be at the begining of the line

Comment: Of course, nobody else will understand the question nor the answer ;-)

Comment: @Jack: I have added some explanations.